# Save Image to File

Tags: php, charts

I am using Google Charts from a URL for example:

> > http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=250x100&chds=0,20...

How do I go about using PHP to save the image. I have tried:

```
$image = file_get_contents($lineChart->getUrl());
file_put_contents('playerchart.png', $image);
```

and

```
$ch = curl_init($lineChart->getUrl());
$fp = fopen('playerchart.png', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

However, both seem to corrupt the image and the image ends up not working.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What does `print_r($lineChart->getUrl())` show, also check your error logs, or rename the file to `playerchart.png.txt` and check it for php errors ect.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following code and I got a proper PNG that I could open in Preview.

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=250x10
0&chds=0,20');
file_put_contents('playerchart.png', $image);
```

Given that the above works, I would say that there is fair chance that there is an issue with the $lineChart->getURL() and it might not be returning exactly what you expect. (I'd say print it out to the screen and double check, there might be some other characters or which space or the like in there. The 'image' that you are saving to disk might actually be the HTML for a 404 page!)

If you'd like an alternative way of saving the file, I would suggest the below. This will fail if the destination URL is not an image.

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng($theurl);
imagepng ($im, 'mypic.png');
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: The exact URL is http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=250x100&chds=0,20&chxr=0,0,20,5&chco=ff3344&chxt=y&chd=t:0,1,7,6,12,17,14,14

Comment: Still worked perfectly pasting the new URL directly into "file_get_contents". Checked in Preview and the graph came out properly. If you are getting a corrupted image then the URL being read is almost certainly not what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php
$img = file_get_contents("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=250x100&chds=0,20");
file_put_contents("test.png", $img);
?>
```

Comment: So what your saying is `$lineChart->getUrl()` could be the point of error?

Comment: Possible: `var_dump($lineChart)` or `var_dump($lineChart->getUrl())` - perhaps that method is returning a bad value :)